# Get moderation notifications on one post only

Tags: pages, notifications, moderation

I'm running a web based community using wordpress multi-site and buddypress.  All users are invited by existing users so no spam accounts exist on site.  Therefore we feel [no need to moderate logged in users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47172/5077).

Since doing this we have found that from now on all moderation requests come from spam attempts.  So I have turned off email notifications for moderation.  One problem, I have a contact page that currently uses comments for non-members to send a message requesting an invite or otherwise get in contact.

Is there any way I can switch moderation notifications on for just this page?

Comment: You should consider using something else than post comments...

Comment: @kaiser What else is there?  I don't want to depend on a plugin, I've got too many dependencies already.

Comment: On a simple Contact form. No need for a plugin, as it could be one of the thousands of cf-php-classes out there also. But: It would (if a plugin) an encapsuled dependency. So: Give it a try. Currently you're trying to scratch your back with your tow. That's kool, but hard to do.

Comment: @kaiser You mean a stand alone contact form outside of wordpress?  I gave up using them because of security issues.

Comment: Try Contact Form 7 - I use it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in the end without using any plugin.  The solution works because this is a multi-site install.  The procedure is quite simple and painless.

1. I created a 'contact' subsite on the subdomain 'http://contact.example.com'
2. I moved the contact 'page' from the main site to the sub site.
3. I enabled comments on this new page, both in wordpress admin, and in the theme.
4. I made the contact page the default home page for the contact site.
5. I changed all links on the main site to the 'contact' form to this new page.
6. I deleted the old page.

I receive email notifications for the 'contact' but not the main site.