# How can I manage all multisite pending comments in one place?

Tags: multisite, comments, moderation

I have a WP multisite installation with a large number of sites.  Thanks to [auto-approving comments from registered users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47172/allowing-logged-in-users-to-comment-without-moderation-across-a-multisite-instal) and invite only registration we no longer need to receive email notifications for comments pending moderation.

This is good and intended behaviour, but it has introduced a further issue.  Some of the sites are accumulating large numbers of 'pending' comments, because its too much hassle for me to regularly visit each of the subsites specific admin page and manage their comments.  Users could manage comments on their own sites, but most can't be bothered.

I wouldn't mind doing it if I had a central interface with which to bulk approve/mark as spam/delete selected pending comments from accross the entire multisite, but I don't want to have to go into each sites admin screen.

Alternatively, list of all sites on the network, with their total pending comments and links to their comment admin page would suffice.  At least then I wouldn't waste time visiting the admin page of sites that don't have pending comments.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can help with this?  I've been searching and searching and can't find anything that gets close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it. but this plugin looks like it satisfies your alternative option

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mu-manage-comments-plugin/

> Conveniently shows a list of blogs with spam or unmoderated comments so that the Network Administrator can manage the the comments on network blogs. The list shows counts by blog with links to each comment.

However. the plugin warns that it might not be suitable for sites with large number of blogs - you may need to tune your PHP timeout value.

Comment: +1 This was almost exactly what I was looking for.  I must remember to search for MU when looking for multi-site plugins.  I'm guessing either my multisite of 50-100 sites is of moderate size, or my VPS is sufficiently powerful to handle this (perhaps it runs slower on shared hosting platforms?)

Comment: Large number in this instance probably means thousands :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugin in the accepted answer is no longer available, I will provide you a solution to your alternative question:

> list of all sites on the network, with their total pending comments and links to their comment admin page

The premium plugin [Beyond Multisite](https://codecanyon.net/item/beyond-multisite-utilities-for-wordpress-network-admins/19633352?ref=nikolaydev), that I have developed, can show you such a list. To see it, after the plugin is activated:

1. Go from the network admin screen to **Dashboard -> Network Cleanup**
2. From the **Comment Status** drop-down menu choose **Pending**
3. Click **Preview Comment Deletion**

[image]

Some benefits are:

1. It will work even if you have a very large network
2. You can choose to see only the sites that have more than 10, 100, 1000, or 10000 pending comments
3. The plugin has other useful features related to WordPress multisite management